# Open a modal from another modal using bootstrap and angularJs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open a modal by clicking on link on the another modal.

Here is my code:

```
.controller('payoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'payoutService',  function($scope, $uibModal, payoutService) {
            console.log('payout');

            var vm = this;

            $scope.openAddPayout    = function(){
                var modalInstance   = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: "app/modules/homePage/payment/Payout/addPayoutMethod.tmpl.html",
                    controller: 'payoutModalCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        payoutMethods: function(){
                            return vm.payoutMethods;
                        }
                    }

                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function() {

                    console.log('success');

                }, function(){
                    //Do stuff with respect to dismissal
                    console.log('error');
                    $state.go('homePage.payment.payout');
                });
            }
        }])
```

the upper modal is getting open and calling the below controller as well.

```
.controller('payoutModalCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance', 'payoutMethods', function($rootScope, $scope, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance, payoutMethods){
                var vm  = this;

                vm.payoutMethods    = payoutMethods;

                vm.pay  = function(method){
                    console.log(method);
                    vm.templateUrl;

                    if(method == 1){
                        vm.templateUrl = "app/modules/homePage/payment/Payout/check.tmpl.html"
                    }
                    else if(method == 2){
                        vm.templateUrl = "app/modules/homePage/payment/Payout/payPal.tmpl.html"
                    }
                    else if(method == 3){
                        vm.templateUrl = "app/modules/homePage/payment/Payout/directDeposite.tmpl.html"
                    }
                    console.log(vm.templateUrl);

                    var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
                    modalScope.modalInstance    = $uibModal.open({
                        templateUrl:vm.templateUrl,
                        controller: 'addPayoutDetailModalCtrl',
                        size: 'sm'
                    });
                }            
            }])
```

on calling **vm.pay** function, another modal should open, where I am getting failed. And the best part I am not able to debug is it is not giving any error.

But from Network and Console from developer tool I have noticed that template is getting called but the controller is not getting call.

```
            .controller('addPayoutDetailModalCtrl', ['$uibModalInstance', 'payoutMethods', function($uibModalInstance, payoutMethods){
               // $uibModalInstance.close();
                console.log('addPayoutDetailModalCtrl call');
        }]);
```

So I am getting the first modal, but from that controller I am not able to open another modal.

Can anyone help!

Comment: for the second modal i see the controller name as 'openModalCtrl', but it should be 'addPayoutDetailModalCtrl' ?

Comment: Do you _really_ need to open a modal from another modal?

Comment: why you haven't passed `vm.templateUrl` and controller `addPayoutDetailModalCtrl` in second modal instance?

Comment: @jos I have changed it. Eventhough it is not working

Comment: Your second one is calling modalInstance.result which refers to the first modal instance.   Should be calling modalScope.modalInstance.result since modalScope.modalInstance is what is decalred in the second controller.

Comment: Why not create a modal with "next" methods? Each option can load a different view of the same model with ng-show where the criteria is met.

Comment: @MansiParekh I have tried that already but nt wrking

Comment: @jbrown I have tried that also nd even if i m not writing the result part the behaviour is same only

Comment: @onmyway can u plz give some reference snipet

Comment: @PiyaModi - addPayoutDetailModalCtrl has a parameter called payoutMethods yet you aren't passing it into your open() via a resolve.

Comment: @PiyaModi I have posted an answer. I did not have time to "trim" the code (although i did), but the idea is to give you some reference as to creating a modal with a next, previous etc. and to hide content you don't want to show, and to show content you want to.

Comment: @jbrown : Yes jbrown ! ur right... silly mistake have been done.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the controllers [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mioyn/6o3ada9j/1/)

```
.controller('payoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $uibModal) {
        console.log('payoutCtrl');

        var vm = this;
        $scope.openAddPayout    = function(){
            var modalInstance   = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: "addPayoutMethod.tmpl.html",
                controller: 'payoutModalCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    payoutMethods: function(){
                        return vm.payoutMethods;
                    }
                }
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                console.log('success');
            }, function(){
                console.log('error');
            });
        }
    }])
    .controller('payoutModalCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance', 'payoutMethods', function($rootScope, $scope, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance, payoutMethods){
            var vm  = this;
                            console.log('payoutModalCtrl');
            vm.payoutMethods    = payoutMethods;

             $scope.pay  = function(method){
                    vm.templateUrl = "check.tmpl.html";
                console.log(vm.templateUrl);

                var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
                modalScope.modalInstance    = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl:vm.templateUrl,
                    controller: 'addPayoutDetailModalCtrl',
                    size: 'sm'
                });
            }            
        }])
.controller('addPayoutDetailModalCtrl', ['$uibModalInstance',   function($uibModalInstance){
            console.log('addPayoutDetailModalCtrl call');
    }]);
```

Comment: Could you please explain what was the issue

Comment: `addPayoutDetailModalCtrl` is injecting `payoutMethods` which i have removed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I have used. I deleted a bunch of stuff just to give you an idea. And the main idea is to hide sections you don't want to show, and to show the sections you want to:

**Controller:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.createReportSchedule')
        .controller('createReportScheduleController', createReportScheduleController);

    createReportScheduleController.$inject = ['logger', 'manageReportSchedulesFactory', '$scope', '$modalInstance'];

    function createReportScheduleController(logger, manageReportSchedulesFactory, $scope, $modalInstance) {
        var vm = $scope;

        vm.isUpdate = false;
        vm.isUpdateNext = false;

        vm.schedule = vm.$parent.schedule;

        vm.ReportSchedule = {};
        vm.SchedulingOptions = {};
        vm.SchedulingUpdateOptions = {};
        vm.ReportFilters = {};

        vm.showReportSchedule = true;

        // Reports Begin
        vm.showMasterCallReport = false;
        vm.showTimeAndMileage = false;
        vm.showAllCallsRemote = false;
        vm.showAllCalls = false;

        // Reports End

        vm.showReportScheduleUpdate = false;

        // Report Modal Data
        vm.MasterCallReportData = null;
        vm.TimeAndMileageReportData = null;
        vm.allCallsRemoteReportData = null;


        // Modal Back Function
        vm.back = function () {
            if (vm.showReportSchedule || vm.showReportScheduleUpdate) {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
            else if (vm.showMasterCallReport) {
                vm.showReportSchedule = true;
                vm.showMasterCallReport = false;
            }
            else if (vm.showTimeAndMileage) {
                vm.showReportSchedule = true;
                vm.showTimeAndMileage = false;
            }
            else if (vm.showAllCallsRemote) {
                vm.showReportSchedule = true;
                vm.showAllCallsRemote = false;
            }
        };

        // Create Report Schedule
        vm.next = function () {
            if (vm.showReportSchedule) {
                if (this.formCreateReportSchedule.$valid) {

                    vm.showReportSchedule = false;
                    vm.isUpdateNext = false;

                    if (vm.ReportSchedule.ReportTemplate.ReportTemplateId == 7) {
                        vm.showMasterCallReport = true;
                        return masterCallReportFactory.getData().then(function (data) {
                            if (logger.displayCommandResult(data)) {
                                vm.MasterCallReportData = data.Records[0];
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (vm.ReportSchedule.ReportTemplate.ReportTemplateId == 8) {
                        vm.showTimeAndMileage = true;
                        return timeAndMileageReportFactory.getData().then(function (data) {
                            if (logger.displayCommandResult(data)) {
                                vm.TimeAndMileageReportData = data.Records[0];
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (vm.ReportSchedule.ReportTemplate.ReportTemplateId == 9) {
                        vm.showAllCallsRemote = true;
                        return allCallsRemoteReportFactory.getData().then(function (data) {
                            if (logger.displayCommandResult(data)) {
                                vm.allCallsRemoteReportData = data.Records[0];
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (vm.ReportSchedule.ReportTemplate.ReportTemplateId == 20) {
                        vm.formSubmmision = true;
                        return vm.postScheduleCreationData();
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.error('Error: Validation failed. Please correct data and try again');
                }
            }

            else if (vm.isUpdate === true) {
                if (this.formUpdateReportSchedule.$valid) {
                    vm.showReportScheduleUpdate = false;
                    vm.isUpdate = false;
                    vm.isUpdateNext = true;

                    if (vm.schedule.ReportTemplate.ReportTemplateId == 7) {
                        vm.showMasterCallReport = true;
                    }
                    if (vm.schedule.ReportTemplate.ReportTemplateId == 8) {
                        vm.showTimeAndMileage = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.error('Error: Validation failed. Please correct data and try again');
                }
            }

            else if (vm.isUpdateNext === true) {
                if (vm.showMasterCallReport || vm.showTimeAndMileage || vm.showAllCallsRemote || vm.showAllCalls || vm.showAllCallsSLALeft
                    || vm.showBreakFix || vm.showCallAssetLine || vm.showDailyStatus || vm.showDailyStatusExtended || vm.showHighPriorityCalls
                    || vm.showSLAMasterCalls || vm.showStockMovement) {

                    // Report Forms
                    if (this.masterCallReport.$valid || this.timeAndMileageReport.$valid || this.allCallsRemoteReport.$valid || this.allCallsReport.$valid
                        || this.allCallsSLALeftReport.$valid || this.callAssetLinesReport.$valid || this.dailyStatusReport.$valid || this.dailyStatusExtendedReport.$valid
                        || this.reportHighPriorityCalls.$valid || this.slaMasterCallReport.$valid || this.stockMovementReport.$valid) {

                        vm.formSubmmision = true;
                        console.log(vm.schedule);
                        return vm.postScheduleUpdateData();
                    }

                } else {
                    return logger.error('Error: Validation failed. Please correct data and try again');
                }
            }

            else if (vm.isUpdateNext === false) {
                if (vm.showMasterCallReport || vm.showTimeAndMileage || vm.showAllCallsRemote || vm.showAllCalls || vm.showAllCallsSLALeft
                    || vm.showBreakFix || vm.showCallAssetLine || vm.showDailyStatus || vm.showDailyStatusExtended || vm.showHighPriorityCalls
                    || vm.showSLAMasterCalls || vm.showStockMovement) {

                    // Report Forms
                    if (this.masterCallReport.$valid || this.timeAndMileageReport.$valid || this.allCallsRemoteReport.$valid || this.allCallsReport.$valid
                        || this.allCallsSLALeftReport.$valid || this.callAssetLinesReport.$valid || this.dailyStatusReport.$valid || this.dailyStatusExtendedReport.$valid
                        || this.reportHighPriorityCalls.$valid || this.slaMasterCallReport.$valid || this.stockMovementReport.$valid) {

                        vm.formSubmmision = true;
                        return vm.postScheduleCreationData();
                    }

                } else {
                    return logger.error('Error: Validation failed. Please correct data and try again');
                }
            }
        };

    }
})();
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Begin Report Schedule Create-->
<form name="formCreateReportSchedule" novalidate ng-show="showReportSchedule">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Report Scheduling Options</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- New Modal -->
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Report Name -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Report Schedule Name:</label>
                <div class="input-text">
                    <input type="text" name="iScheduleName" ng-model="ReportSchedule.ScheduleName" ng-required="true" />
                    <div class="fadeInOut" ng-class="{error : iScheduleNameError}" ng-mouseenter="iScheduleNameError = true" ng-mouseleave="iScheduleNameError = false" ng-show="(formCreateReportSchedule.$submitted || formCreateReportSchedule.iScheduleName.$touched) && formCreateReportSchedule.iScheduleName.$error.required">
                        <span class="icon-warning"></span>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <span>Please Enter a Schedule Name</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Report Template -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Report Type</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Report Name"
                                 ng-model="ReportSchedule.ReportTemplate"
                                 ng-options="SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportTemplates"
                                 cc-fields="ReportTemplateName"
                                 cc-key-field="ReportTemplateId"
                                 cc-allow-search="SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportTemplates != null && SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportTemplates.length > 5"
                                 ng-required="true"
                                 name="iReportTemplate">
                    </cc-dropdown>
                    <div class="fadeInOut" ng-class="{error : iReportTemplateError}" ng-mouseenter="iReportTemplateError = true" ng-mouseleave="iReportTemplateError = false" ng-show="(formCreateReportSchedule.$submitted || formCreateReportSchedule.iReportTemplate.$touched) && formCreateReportSchedule.iReportTemplate.$error.required">
                        <span class="icon-warning"></span>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <span>Please Select a Template</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Hours -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Execution Time</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Report Time"
                                 ng-model="ReportSchedule.ExecutionTime"
                                 ng-options="SelectableExecutionTimes"
                                 cc-fields="<self>"
                                 cc-allow-search="true"
                                 ng-required="true"
                                 name="iExecutionTime">
                    </cc-dropdown>
                    <div class="fadeInOut" ng-class="{error : iExecutionTimeError}" ng-mouseenter="iExecutionTimeError = true" ng-mouseleave="iExecutionTimeError = false" ng-show="(formCreateReportSchedule.$submitted || formCreateReportSchedule.iExecutionTime.$touched) && formCreateReportSchedule.iExecutionTime.$error.required">
                        <span class="icon-warning"></span>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <span>Please Select an Execution Time</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Reporting Period -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Period</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Reporting Period"
                                 ng-model="ReportSchedule.ReportPeriod"
                                 ng-options="SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportingPeriods"
                                 cc-fields="ReportPeriodName"
                                 cc-key-field="ReportPeriodId"
                                 cc-allow-search="SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportPeriods != null && SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportPeriods.length > 5"
                                 ng-required="true"
                                 name="iReportPeriod">
                    </cc-dropdown>
                    <div class="fadeInOut" ng-class="{error : iReportPeriodError}" ng-mouseenter="iReportPeriodError = true" ng-mouseleave="iReportPeriodError = false" ng-show="(formCreateReportSchedule.$submitted || formCreateReportSchedule.iReportPeriod.$touched) && formCreateReportSchedule.iReportPeriod.$error.required">
                        <span class="icon-warning"></span>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <span>Please Select a Reporting Period</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Frequency -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Frequency</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Report Frequency"
                                 ng-model="ReportSchedule.ReportFrequency"
                                 ng-options="SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportFrequencies"
                                 ng-change="frequencyChanged()"
                                 cc-fields="ReportFrequencyName"
                                 cc-key-field="ReportFrequencyId"
                                 cc-allow-search="SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportFrequencies != null && SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportFrequencies.length > 5"
                                 ng-required="true"
                                 name="iReportFrequency">
                    </cc-dropdown>
                    <div class="fadeInOut" ng-class="{error : iReportFrequencyError}" ng-mouseenter="iReportFrequencyError = true" ng-mouseleave="iReportFrequencyError = false" ng-show="(formCreateReportSchedule.$submitted || formCreateReportSchedule.iReportFrequency.$touched) && formCreateReportSchedule.iReportFrequency.$error.required">
                        <span class="icon-warning"></span>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <span>Please Select a Report Frequency</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Frequency Options -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Frequency Options</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Report Frequency Option"
                                 ng-model="ReportSchedule.ReportFrequencyOption"
                                 ng-options="FrequencyOptions"
                                 ng-disabled="FrequencyOptions.length == 0"
                                 cc-fields="ReportFrequencyOptionName"
                                 cc-key-field="ReportFrequencyOptionId"
                                 cc-allow-search="SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportFrequencyOptions != null && SchedulingOptions.SelectableReportFrequencyOptions.length > 5"
                                 ng-required="FrequencyOptions.length != 0"
                                 name="iReportFrequencyOption">
                    </cc-dropdown>
                    <div class="fadeInOut" ng-class="{error : iReportFrequencyOptionError}" ng-mouseenter="iReportFrequencyOptionError = true" ng-mouseleave="iReportFrequencyOptionError = false" ng-show="(formCreateReportSchedule.$submitted || formCreateReportSchedule.iReportFrequencyOption.$touched) && formCreateReportSchedule.iReportFrequencyOption.$error.required">
                        <span class="icon-warning"></span>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <span>Please Select a Report Frequency Option</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Email -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Recipient Email:</label>
                <div class="input-text">
                    <input type="text" name="iEmail" ng-required="true" ng-model="ReportSchedule.EmailRecipients" />
                    <div class="fadeInOut" ng-class="{error : iEmailError}" ng-mouseenter="iEmailError = true" ng-mouseleave="iEmailError = false" ng-show="(formCreateReportSchedule.$submitted || formCreateReportSchedule.iEmail.$touched) && formCreateReportSchedule.iEmail.$error.required">
                        <span class="icon-warning"></span>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                <span>Please Enter a Recipient Email Address</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- row -->
    </div> <!--body-->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning left" ng-click="back()" ng-disabled="formSubmmision">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary right" type="submit" ng-click="next()" ng-disabled="formSubmmision">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>

<!-- Selected Report Settings: Master Call Report -->
<form name="masterCallReport" novalidate ng-show="showMasterCallReport">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Schedule: Master Call Report</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Customer -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Customer</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Select a Customer"
                                 ng-model="MasterCallReportData.Customer"
                                 ng-options="MasterCallReportData.SelectableCustomer"
                                 cc-fields="CustomerName"
                                 cc-key-field="CustomerId"
                                 cc-allow-search="MasterCallReportData.SelectableCustomer != null && MasterCallReportData.SelectableCustomer.length > 5"
                                 name="iCustomer">
                    </cc-dropdown>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Resolver Group -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Resolver Group</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="ALL Resolver Groups"
                                 ng-model="MasterCallReportData.ResolverGroup"
                                 ng-options="MasterCallReportData.SelectableResolverGroup"
                                 cc-fields="ResolverGroupDescription"
                                 cc-key-field="ResolverGroupId"
                                 cc-allow-search="MasterCallReportData.SelectableResolverGroup != null && MasterCallReportData.SelectableResolverGroup.length > 5"
                                 name="iResolverGroup">
                    </cc-dropdown>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Region -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Region</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="ALL Regions"
                                 ng-model="MasterCallReportData.Region"
                                 ng-options="MasterCallReportData.SelectableRegion"
                                 cc-fields="RegionDescription"
                                 cc-key-field="RegionId"
                                 cc-allow-search="MasterCallReportData.SelectableRegion != null && MasterCallReportData.SelectableRegion.length > 5"
                                 name="iRegion">
                    </cc-dropdown>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Status -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Status</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Open"
                                 ng-model="MasterCallReportData.CallStatus"
                                 ng-options="MasterCallReportData.SelectableStatus"
                                 cc-fields="Status + ' - ' + Reason"
                                 cc-key-field="CallStatusId"
                                 cc-allow-search="MasterCallReportData.SelectableStatus != null && MasterCallReportData.SelectableStatus.length > 5"
                                 name="iStatus">
                    </cc-dropdown>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Affected End User -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Affected End User</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Select a Contact Person"
                                 ng-model="MasterCallReportData.AffectedEndUser"
                                 ng-options="MasterCallReportData.SelectableAffectedEndUser"
                                 cc-fields="FullName"
                                 cc-key-field="ContactPersonId"
                                 cc-allow-search="MasterCallReportData.SelectableAffectedEndUser != null && MasterCallReportData.SelectableAffectedEndUser.length > 5"
                                 name="iAffectedEndUser">
                    </cc-dropdown>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Resolution Method -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Resolution Method</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="ALL Method"
                                 ng-model="MasterCallReportData.ResolutionMethod"
                                 ng-options="MasterCallReportData.SelectableResolutionMethod"
                                 cc-fields="ResolutionMethodDescription"
                                 cc-key-field="ResolutionMethodId"
                                 cc-allow-search="false"
                                 name="iResolutionMethod">
                    </cc-dropdown>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- SLA Filter -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>SLA Filter</label>
                <div class="input-text">
                    <input type="text" name="iSLAFilter" ng-model="MasterCallReportData.SLAFilter" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Logged By -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Logged By</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="Select an Employee"
                                 ng-model="MasterCallReportData.LoggedBy"
                                 ng-options="MasterCallReportData.SelectableLoggedBy"
                                 cc-fields="FullName"
                                 cc-key-field="EmployeeId"
                                 cc-allow-search="MasterCallReportData.SelectableLoggedBy != null && MasterCallReportData.SelectableLoggedBy.length > 5"
                                 name="iLoggedBy">
                    </cc-dropdown>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Call Priority -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Call Priority</label>
                <div class="input-dropdown">
                    <cc-dropdown cc-placeholder="ALL Priorities"
                                 ng-model="MasterCallReportData.Priority"
                                 ng-options="MasterCallReportData.SelectableCallPriority"
                                 cc-fields="CallPriorityDescription"
                                 cc-key-field="CallPriorityId"
                                 cc-allow-search="false"
                                 name="iPriority">
                    </cc-dropdown>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- SLA Breaching Warning -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>SLA Breaching Warning</label>
                <div class="input-switch">
                    <input id="toggle-2" class="toggle toggle-yes-no" type="checkbox" ng-model="MasterCallReportData.SLABreachWarning">
                    <label for="toggle-2" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Logged -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Logged</label>
                <div class="input-switch">
                    <input id="toggle-3" class="toggle toggle-yes-no" type="checkbox" ng-model="MasterCallReportData.Logged">
                    <label for="toggle-3" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Resolved -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Resolved</label>
                <div class="input-switch">
                    <input id="toggle-4" class="toggle toggle-yes-no" type="checkbox" ng-model="MasterCallReportData.Resolved">
                    <label for="toggle-4" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- Row End-->

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning left" ng-click="back()" ng-disabled="formSubmmision">Back</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary right" type="submit" ng-click="next()" ng-disabled="formSubmmision">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>
```